# Pipe input to another process one line at a time

Tags: pipe

I have a script which can take one file name at a time and I want to run it for many files in a folder. So, I want to pipe the output of:

```
find . -iname '*.m'
```

to my script but one line at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for xargs.

find . -iname '*.m' | xargs yourscript

xargs reads items from the standard input, delimited by blanks or newlines, and executes the command (default is /bin/echo) one or more times with any  initial-arguments  followed  by items read from standard input.

Comment: Awesome. This worked for me. My script also took some other options, so I did: find myfolder/ -iname '*.js' | xargs ./doMoreStuff.js -r